# Formatting date in excel for csv upload

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, text-formatting

I am looking to upload a csv file to Google apps. I am outputting my date from SQL as `mm/dd/yy` but when I try and save it in excel as a csv it changes my date format to `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Is there a way to save my `mm/dd/yy` format in csv file.  Can I convert it to a text and save it as a csv?

Comment: First, CSV is text. Second, now that you know that, open the CSV in notepad and paste a line here (replace any identifiable info first)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is:

```
=TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yy")
```

Alternatively, you can custom format the actual date cell (A1 in the formula above) by right clicking → Format Cells → Custom and entering the same format (`mm/dd/yy`).

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good chance you're trying to solve something that isn't even a problem. Just do the import and see if it works.

Your question could use some more detail, but here is a key piece of information: **Excel and Google Spreadsheets both treat dates as regular numbers** (number of days since Jan 1, 1900). Whether you see a date as `8/25/14` or `8/25/2014` or `2014-08-25` or `25 August 2014` or `41876` is simply a display issue, and does not affect the data itself.

You can type `41876` into either Excel or Google Spreadsheets and then format it as a date to get `8/25/2014`.